# workaround for MILP equation 'a ≥ X ≥ b' becomes infeasible when variable b > a

Tags: optimization, cplex

What I wrote in the title is trivial. But I am wondering, if there is some workaround with MILP for this kind of problem.

lets assume my equation looks the following:

X and a are time-dependent variables.
b is a fix time serie.

X should always be between a and b, so 
a ≥ X ≥ b

But it may happen that b contains values that are taller than the maximum limit of a. In that case I would like to say a = X or 0 = X or anything.

How can I tackle this problem? I've thought about it for a while and all solution I or my colleague come up with end up being not MILP equations. Maybe it's undoable.

Comment: We cannot have constraints of the form `a > X > b` in optimization. You need to say something like `b[t] <= x[t] <= a[t]`.  Usually we set bounds on `x[t]`: no constraints are needed to model this. If you occasionally have `b[t]>a[t]` then write: `min(a[t],b[t]) <= x[t] <= a[t]`. These are still just lower and upper-bounds on `x[t]`.

Comment: You're right. I edited the original post. But why do you propose the min() function? min() cannot be used in MILP.

Comment: I missed that b is constant and a is variable (proof that good notation always helps). You need extra binary variables to model this.

Comment: Sorry, you’re right. You can always propose edits to make it more clear :) about the binary variables: Since binary variables cannot be multiplied them with the variables, what can be done here?

Answer (score 1):

Let me restate the problem in a notation that is more familiar to me. We have variables `x[t]` and `y[t]` and constants `u[t]`. We want to model:

```
  y[t] <= x[t] <= u[t]  if y[t] <= u[t]
  x[t] = y[t]           if y[t] >  u[t]
```

We can rewrite this as:

```
  y[t] <= x[t] <= max(u[t],y[t])
```

or

```
  y[t] <= x[t]
  x[t] <= u[t] + M δ[t]
  x[t] <= y[t] + M (1-δ[t])
  δ[t] ∈ {0,1}
```

where `M` is a large enough constant (but not too large). If there is no good way to get a good value for `M` we can use indicator constraints or SOS1 variables (not all solvers support these).